# Setting similarity threshold for trigram_similar Django PostgreSQL lookups?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-views, django-queryset

We're using [Django's trigram similarity](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/#trigram-similarity) `__trigram_similar` lookup and it works nicely, except we want to adjust the similarity threshold and don't know how. Queries are currently filtered like so:

```py
class MarkerViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    queryset = tablename.objects.all()

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        queryset = super().filter_queryset(queryset)
        queryset = queryset.filter(colname__trigram_similar= search_value)
```

We thought we could add something like `similarity__gt=0.1` to the args for `filter()` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44012948) does, but it throws the error "django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'similarity_gt' into field". They are using the `.filter()` function in a different way we don't understand which might be the problem. What's the argument and how can we supply it?

Seems we might be able to [adjust it manually in PostgreSQL with `set_limit`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-FUNC-TABLE) (previously `SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold`), but we'd prefer to set this in Django.